# (numpy.random.standard_t) How to determine degrees of freedom?

Tags: python, statistics, distribution

Please advise me how to determine degrees of freedom

## 1. I use the follow code to plot a student-t distribution with a histogram

```
# distribution fitting
param = t.fit(log_rets) 
# now get theoretical values in our interval      
pdf_t = stats.t.pdf(lnspc, param[0], param[1], param[2])
# plot it      
plt.plot(lnspc, pdf_t, label="student t") 
plt.show()
```

## 2. I found the param[3] as the following

```
(3.1512592116146094, 0.00046753124755725029, 0.0061044503250347361)
```

## 3. I would generate a random number with student-t, but don't know how to determine degrees of freedom

```
retvec = []
for i in range (n_obs):
    retvec.append(np.random.standard_t(**<degrees of freedom>**, size=n_assets))
```

Please feel free to comment.

Regards, Nelson.

Comment: My understanding of degrees of freedom is that its the number of independent variables or parameters.  Do you know how many independent variables there are or should be? Since pdf_t has 3 parameters maybe you need to use 3 as the number of degrees of freedom. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom for info about degrees of freedom.

Comment: Thank you. I shall take a look of your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This is old question, but for anyone reading it, params[0] here is degrees of freedom (e.g., tail size), so you can generate your random values with scipy random variates:

```
roll = stats.t.rvs(df=params[0], loc=params[1], scale=params[2], size=n_assets)
```